# How to override Django allauth to customize registeration?

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-allauth, django-custom-user

I'm having trouble customizing the allauth registration module, where I cannot get rid of the Username field. I did take all required measures in the settings.py file to override it, for instance :

```
"""
Django settings for mackta project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 2.2.3.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'f!0kitfww9lbpk+5uppbq)#an(#poh*t9is3&$=#8o!*a#y5e&'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',

    'mackta_api',

    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'rest_auth',
    'rest_auth.registration',

    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',

]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mackta.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mackta.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'mackta_api.UserProfile'

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    )
}

REST_AUTH_REGISTER_SERIALIZERS = {
    'REGISTER_SERIALIZER' : 'mackta_api.api.serializers.CustomRegisterSerializer'
}

SITE_ID = 1

ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = 'none'
ACCOUNT_USER_MODEL_USERNAME_FIELD = None
# USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = False
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'email'
```

I did implement REST_AUTH_REGISTER_SERIALIZERS to specify the fields that I am willing to use for registration.

settings.py

```
REST_AUTH_REGISTER_SERIALIZERS = {
    'REGISTER_SERIALIZER' : 'mackta_api.api.serializers.CustomRegisterSerializer'
}

SITE_ID = 1

ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = 'none'
ACCOUNT_USER_MODEL_USERNAME_FIELD = None
# USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = False
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'email'
```

serializers.py

```
class CustomRegisterSerializer(RegisterSerializer):
    first_name = serializers.CharField(required=True, max_length=100,)
    last_name = serializers.CharField(required=True, max_length=100)
    email = serializers.EmailField(required=allauth_settings.EMAIL_REQUIRED)
    password = serializers.CharField(required=True, write_only=True)


    def get_cleaned_data(self):
        super(CustomRegisterSerializer, self).get_cleaned_data()
        return {
            'first_name' : self.validated_data.get('first_name', ''),
            'last_name' : self.validated_data.get('last_name', ''),
            'email' : self.validated_data.get('email', ''),
            'password' : self.validated_data.get('password', '')
        }
```

models.py

```
class UserProfileManager(BaseUserManager):
    # """userprofile """

    def create_user(self, email, first_name, last_name, password=None):
        # """userprofile instance """
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Invalid e-mail address')

        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name)

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()

        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, first_name, last_name, password):
        # """creating superuser instance"""
        user = self.create_user(email, first_name, last_name, password)

        user.is_superuser = True
        user.is_staff = True
        user.save()

        return user


class UserProfile(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    # """db model for users in the system"""
    # user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    user_name = None

    objects = UserProfileManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'last_name'] 

    def get_full_name(self):
        """retreive full name of user"""
        return f"{self.first_name} {self.last_name}"

    def get_short_name(self):
        """retreive short name of user"""
        return self.first_name

    def __str__(self):
        """return string representation of our user"""
        return self.first_name
```

Comment: can you please post your complete `settings.py` code.

Comment: actually what i want to see is that do you overwrite the user model or not.

Comment: @Shakil yes i did overwrite the user model to use custom model user

Comment: you need to make sure in your user model that you `unrequired` your user_name field. If possible please your `User` model too.

Comment: @Shakil will do

Comment: @Shakil please how do you unrequire the user_name field???